# Excel - Lookup to match varying criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, lookup

I have a list of poles, some with more than one test result.  I want to find the latest test result for each pole and then return the result.  As we know, `VLOOKUP` only finds the first.  I don't want to have to sort and re-sort the data every time.

So:  three key values:  col a = dates of tests, col b = poll number, col fa = test result.

I have a growing list of over 5,000 poles!

Thanks!

Comment: databases are best suited for complex queries.

Comment: Please give us an example of how this data is stored. And I assume you mean “polls”.

Comment: Have you considered using a pivot table/report?

Comment: Hi DHA - nope, I do mean poles.  Here's an example: 
 
Date of Test Pole No./ID Advanced Pole Status
23/08/2011 5334         END STATUS : Serviceable
14/02/2014 5334         END STATUS : Reject

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity, I'm going to assume your summary table is in the same sheet beginning at `E1`.  You will need to update all of the following references to the actual data table.  I have it set up it like so:

[image]

1. The first column represents the poll.  Place the name or number of the poll in this column.  This should match the name or number listed in the data table, and it should match exactly.  If it is not exact, this will not work.
2. The second column represents the latest date.  Use the following array formula and be sure to hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> while you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Holding these keys creates an array formula.

   `=MAX(IF(B:B = E2, A:A, 0))`

   After you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the formula should be surrounded with curly brackets like so: `{=MAX(IF(B:B = F2, A:A, 0))}`.  The curly brackets identify the formula as an array formula.  If they are not present, re-enter the cell and try to press the key sequence again.  Note that you should not actually type the curly brackets, they appear automatically.
3. Lastly, the third column represents the latest result.  This will also be an array formula so be sure to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> while you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   `=INDEX(C:C, MATCH(F2 & " " & E2, A:A & " " & B:B, 0))`

Since Excel treats dates as numbers, we can use the `MAX` formula to find the latest one.  To limit this to a specific poll, we use an array formula to tell Excel to loop through the dates and if it is not the poll we want, to use the number 0 instead of the date.  This effectively excludes the non-matching polls.  Once we have the latest date, we just need to fetch the result, and since we are referencing two columns, we need to combine them in some way, which we accomplish by concatenating the date and poll together with a space inbetween.  The `MATCH` formula searches for an exact match and returns the position of the first match it finds, which corresponds to the row number in this case.  The `INDEX` formula is then used to retrieve the result.

Note that the first result will be returned if there are more than one matching date and poll.

Comment: Hi there Jason - thanks for that. I think I can see the logic in your formulae. However, there is one thing that confuses me: e.g. 1st formula: if I want the result to show in F2, why am I referring to it in the formula? That would create a circular reference.    **PS  I think a well meaning moderator or someone changed my spelling:  I am talking about poles, as in electricity poles.  Not important for this purpose though.  :-)

Comment: You are correct.  It was supposed to be E2.  It has been corrected.